# Realm - Anonymous user sync to new device

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I understand that Realm provides [anonymous user logins](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/users).

> Even if your app does not require the user to login and create a
>   unique account we still recommend that your app, in user code, logs in
>   with a randomly generated user that occurs in the background of the
>   user using the app; we have created anonymous user explicitly for this
>   purpose.

The main reason I want to use Realm though is to sync data between devices. For example a user creates a note on their iPhone, it should also appear on their iPad, if they have the app installed on both devices. I don't understand how this is possible if the user is anonymous. Does my requirement mean that I need to force the user to log in (non-anonymously) on both devices? If so, what is the use case for an anonymous user?

Related, if I have an anonymous user, how would I covert them into a "logged-in" user? I want to let the user use the app without logging in. If I need them to log in, I only want to do it when they've upgraded to "pro" or a paid subscription, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line for anonymous users is this statement from the [Sync Docs](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/user-authentication/username-password-provider#anonymous-authentication)

> Realm Platform provides a built-in authentication provider which
>   supports Username/Password and **Anonymous login for development and**
>   **proof of concept usage.**

Anonymous Authentication is enabled by default on Realm and it's really for testing as any Anonymous user connected to a Realm has access to Realm data.

Based on that if you have three devices and each one connects to Realm A, then all devices will have access to the data on Realm A. During development, it takes complex authentication off the plate so you can focus on the syncing and UI components of the app.

There is no current direct way to convert an anonymous user to a 'logged-in' user but there is an open github issue for that [#2211](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/2211)

Once you start working on authentication, you can control permissions via [Access Control](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/access-control) which can control what data users can access.

When we begin development, we create an Admin user via Realm Studio and then hard code that into our app (again, only for development) because:

> Admin users can always read or write from any Realm.

Comment: Is there an up-to-date example on how to create a full authentication process to avoid hardcoding Admin user, and avoid using Anonymous user, but keep it all transparent for the app user. I have never been able to find a working example for this process and most of information online and even in Realm docs is out of date and not working. Especially Realm docs are the worst.

Comment: @zeeshan We just craft a login sheet or viewController where the user enters their name and password. We give them an option to store their username (in user defaults) but requires password entry each time.

Answer (score 1):

As per Realm Docs

> Subscriptions are automatically persisted and maintained by the
>   server. When data changes occur the server will reevaluate existing
>   subscriptions and push the changes to all subscribing clients.

---

So lets have an example of syncing.

1. **Authentication**

   ```
   guard let authURL = URL(string: "Realm Instance URL") else {
       return
   }

   let credentials = SyncCredentials.anonymous()

   SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: authURL) { (user, error) in

       if let realmUser = user {
           // User logged in successfully
       } else if let realmError = error {
           print(realmError.localizedDescription)
       }

   }
   ```
2. **Realm Instantiation**

   ```
   let realmURL = URL(string: "Realm URL")
   let config = realmUser.configuration(realmURL: realmURL)
   let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
   ```
3. **Declear following variables globaly**

   ```
   private var itemsSyncSubscription: SyncSubscription?
   private var itemsSubscriptionToken: NotificationToken?
   private var itemsNotificationToken: NotificationToken?
   ```
4. **Subscribe for data/table (i.e. Item)**

   ```
   let items = realm.objects(Item.self)
   itemsSyncSubscription = items.subscribe()
   itemsSubscriptionToken = itemsSyncSubscription?.observe(\.state, options: .initial, { (state) in

       switch state {

       case .complete:

           // This will be called when Items will be fetched from Realm first time
           print(items)

       case .error(let error):
           completion(error)

       default: break

       }

   })

   itemsNotificationToken = items.observe { (changes) in

       switch changes {

       case .initial:
           print("Items Subscription Initial State")/

       case .update(_, _, _, _):

           print("Items Subscription Update State")/
           // This will be called whenever any change will happens in Items table.

       case .error(let error):
           print("Items Subscription error :\(error)")/

       }

   }
   ```

So in short, any logged-in user from any authentication method will be notified whenever any change will happens into data source.

Comment: @tariq While there is some good info in this answer, (query based) synchronized realms appear to be or are about to be depreciated which means syncSubscriptions should probably not be used at this point in favor of Full Sync. See the docs [Query-based Sync](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/access-control/fine-grained-permissions) which state *Query-based Sync is not recommended. For applications using Realm Sync, we recommend Full Sync*. The code for accessing realm in 1) and 2) is spot on and pretty much straight from the docs.